# Usertesting from a distance... with old hardware

Tags: usability-testing

A large group of our clients uses old hardware to buy our products online. They like our webshop and want to help improve their experience.
So when we want to do usertesting we try to visit them, it's fun and very usefull.

But now with COVID and everything we aren't allowed to visit, but we want to continue testing. Using tools like Lookback has been an issue since their hardware doesn't have webcam or the proper browser (version).

Do you have any advice when it comes to (online) tooling or practices with usertesting from a distance?

Comment: I'm assuming your website is accessed by your users via desktop. You could use a tool like Maze for unmoderated user testing.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like Google hangouts, zoom, Skype etc and let them share their screen. Have done this for quite some time, works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated earlier, Google Hangouts, Zoom and such are great tools for testing usability remotely. However if you want some advanced features it might not be enough. Here is a site that should help you. https://www.usability-testing.org/usability-testing-methods/ Here you can find all the info about many  types of usability testing and how to do them (with some tools that might fit your description).